# How to make NSView not clip its bounding area?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit

I created an empty Cocoa app on Xcode for OS X, and added:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    self.view.wantsLayer = YES;
    self.view.layer = [CALayer layer];
    self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor yellowColor] CGColor];
    self.view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30 * M_PI / 180, 1, 1, 1);

    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.view];
}
```

But the rotated layer's background is clipped by the view's bounding area:

[image]

I thought since some version of OS X and iOS, the view won't clip the content of its subviews and will show everything inside and outside?  On iOS, I do see that behavior, but I wonder why it shows up like that and how to make everything show? (I am already using the most current Xcode 4.4.1 on Mountain Lion).

(note: if you try the code above, you will need to link to Quartz Core, and possibly import the quartz core header, although I wonder why I didn't import the header and it still compiles perfectly)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that if the line:

```
((NSView *)self.window.contentView).wantsLayer = YES;
```

is added to the very beginning, then it works as expected:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{  
    ((NSView *)self.window.contentView).wantsLayer = YES;

    self.view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200, 200, 200, 200)];

    self.view.wantsLayer = YES;

    self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor yellowColor] CGColor];

    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.view];
    self.view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30 * M_PI / 180, 0, 0, 1);

}
```

So it looks like if all the views are made to be layer backed, then it works the same as it does on iOS.  (If there is a quick way to make all views layer backed automatically, that'd be good).

the `anchorPoint` line cannot be moved before `addSubview` line, or else it is incorrect, although I wonder why that would make any difference.

The line `self.view.layer = [CALayer layer];` can be removed if `window.contentView` is layer backed.  Both the contentView and `self.view` don't need to set the layer, and I wonder why too.

The `transform` line cannot be before the `addSubview` line, or else it won't rotate, and I wonder why too.

The third thing is that, I thought if I go to Interface Builder and make the contentView a class of `ContentView` (subclassing `NSView`), and in its `init` method, do a `self.wantsLayer = YES;`, then it would work too, but it does not.

But anyway, the code above works, and I will update the reasons above why when I find out more.

[image]

Comment: I'm a iOS developer and I have recently started working in Cocoa. This has been driving me crazy for the last three days.  I'm surprised I can't find more information about it.  Thank you for posting your solution!!

Comment: There might be problems when you mix NSView with layers and ones without layers.  It is not stable that which content will overlay on the others.

Comment: Setting `self.wantsLayer = YES` does not work in `init` because 1. the  correct initializer is `initWithFrame:` and 2. even this is not called for views loaded from nibs. You should override `-awakeFromNib` and perform your setup there. Alternatively, you can set the Core Animation Layer property in IB’s View Effects inspector.