# Why does a CATransform3DMakeRotation not take (0,0,1) as rotating around the Z-axis?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, catransform3d

If I do a transform to an `NSView` in Cocoa's app:

```
self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30 * M_PI / 180, 0, 0, 1);
```

I see the square not rotated around the Z-axis, but rotated as if that vector is pointing downward and outward.  I need to make it

```
self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30 * M_PI / 180, 1, 1, 1);
```

to make it rotate around the Z-axis, as shown in the picture on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400273/how-to-make-nsview-not-clip-its-bounding-area).

However, if I set an `NSTimer` and then update the `transform` in the `update` method, then using

```
-(void) update:(id) info {
    self.view.layer.transform = 
                  CATransform3DMakeRotation(self.degree * M_PI / 180, 0, 0, 1);
    self.degree += 10;
}
```

(this time, using `(0, 0, 1)`) will work: it rotates around the Z-axis.  I wonder why `(1, 1, 1)` is needed inside of `applicationDidFinishLaunching` , but `(0, 0, 1)` can be used in the `update` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the view needs to be added to `window.contentView` first:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{    
    self.view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 200, 200)];

    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.view];

    self.view.wantsLayer = YES;
    self.view.layer = [CALayer layer];

    self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor yellowColor] CGColor];
    self.view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30 * M_PI / 180, 0, 0, 1); 
}
```

also, the line `self.view.layer = [CALayer layer];` needs to be after the line `self.view.wantsLayer = YES;`.  Why these order, I am not sure, but it works as it is supposed to.  I can't find the docs that mentions the requirement for this order yet, but the code above works.  I will update the answer when I find more info about why the order is needed.

Comment: This solved an related issue of my app on macOS 10.13 only: The anchor point always been changed from center to (0,0). Thank you!