# CAGradientLayer on UILabel can't be rotated

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, core-graphics, cagradientlayer

I want a horizontal color gradient as the text color of my `UILabel`.
So I'm using a `CAGradientLayer` as described in https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cagradientlayer.
The gradient is rendered perfectly on the text, but vertically.

`CATransform3DMakeRotation` as apple described doesn't rotate the gradient.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12434563) it says that the `CAGradientLayer` needs to be added to a View or other Layer first to make the rotation work.

So I tried to add it as a sublayer to my UILabel and remove it after the rendering, but it won't transform the gradient on the text, but adds a horizontal gradient rectangle on top of it, in the size of the UILabel but rotated 90°.

Here's my code:

```
extension UILabel {
func addGradient() {
    // Get size of the label
    let size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.width)

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.height, height: size.width)

    gradientLayer.colors = [
        UIColor.gradientBlue.cgColor,
        UIColor.gradientPink.cgColor,
        UIColor.gradientOrange.cgColor
    ]

    //        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    gradientLayer.transform = CGAffineTransform

    // This does not work
    gradientLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    // Create UIImage from Gradient
    let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //        gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

    textColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: gradientImage!)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 1, y: 1)
```

for diagonal gradient. you can play with those points however you want to achieve different results.

Comment: Works like a charme, thank you so much! This should be also a hint in the official documentation!

Comment: glad it helped :)