# Subview of NSView get clipped when using CATransform3DMakeTranslation on layer of NSView

Tags: cocoa, translation, transform, catransform3d

I have a NSView with three NSImageView subviews.  I'm having trouble with the subviews clipping when I use CATransform3DMakeTranslation to translate along the x axis.

I primarily do iOS development and this is my first go in this realm.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to turn the Core Animation Layer on for the content view of my window.  I found the answer here: [How to make NSView not clip its bounding area?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12400273/703910)